# JqueryMobile (JQM), Json and passing data to a new page

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-mobile

Hope you all are fine and rocking your code editors.

My question is how to pass url rel to a new page to use it in future?

Let me give you an example that will work better than 1000 words.

On page "A" I have url to page "B", to load page "B" html I pointing that url straight to page "B" as `<a href="page-B.html" rel="{{id}}">{{deptName}}</a>` (don't look at `{{}}` it is Mustache.js tags).

So when I am clicking on that link it is working as it should, pointing me to page "B" and loading my new html layout (that is different from page "A").

Now because I am fetching data from JSON I need to pass `rel="{{id}}"` to a page-B to tell what data I want from the JSON.

Any good ideas or practical code how you do that?

Thank you!

P.S.

On page "B" in $.delegate I need that id to do something like that:

```
$.ajax({
        beforeSend: function() { $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg() }, //Show spinner
        complete: function() { $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg() }, //Hide spinner
        url: 'http://website.com/categoryJSON.ashx?&catId=THE_ID&callback=?',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var template = $('#pageCategoryTpl').html();
            var html = Mustache.to_html(template, data);
            $('[data-role=content]:first').html(html);
        }
    });
```

Comment: 2 questions  - what have you tired? and is page B an external page or part of a multi-page template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a simple solution and it is **window.sessionStorage**.

In my particular case scenarion I am clicking on URL/link, getting href (this where my id is), saving that with **window.sessionStorage**, changing **window.location** to the new page and do my JSON magic.

The code:

On page "A":

```
$('a').live('click', function(){

        var currentID = $(this).attr('href');

        window.sessionStorage.setItem('parentId', currentID);

        window.location = 'page-B.html';

        return false;

        });
```

On page "B":

```
var parentId = sessionStorage.getItem('parentId');

$.ajax({
 url: 'http://www.url.com/file.json?id=' + parentId + '',
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(data) {
    alert('Success!');
 }
});
```

Vuala! Hope that will help someone.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following way to transfer multiple data across pages.

HTML

```
<a href="#detail?id=1234&another_id=5678" id="carrier-btn" data-role="button">link button with extra data</a>
```

JS

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function(evt, data) {
    var id = queryParam("id"); //def of queryParam() in below fiddle
    var anotherId = queryParam("another_id");
    //console.log(id);
    //console.log("page show", evt, data);
    $(evt.target).find("#queryData").text(id);
    $(evt.target).find("#queryData1").text(anotherId);
});
```

Full source http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/MPmJH/

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variable to achieve your problem instead of passing query string(Url data).

ex:

```
// Your global variable 
var global_varible = '';
```

In page A,

global_varible = your_data;

And in page B, You can access global_varible