# How to pass Array of JSON Data from one html page to other html page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I am creating profile page for user. I have two html page: **page1: login.html** and **page2:profile.html**. From one page:1 we login, after successfully login, it will redirect to userProfile page:2. I am sending the user info from page1 to 
page2, like Name, Address, Mobile Number, Email-Id etc, in form of JSON,

**I want to use sesstion, but not localStorage**

**Format of JSON is**

```
[{"userInfo":{"id":"1","username":"nee","Name":"Neelabh", "address":"Bangalore","Email":"nee@gmail.com"}}]
```

I use this reference for help: [JqueryMobile (JQM), Json and passing data to a new page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911890/jquerymobile-jqm-json-and-passing-data-to-a-new-page)

**JavaScript in Login Page:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">     
    $(document).ready(function(){       
                var userData = {
                 storeUserDataInSession: function(userData) {
                     var userObjectString = JSON.stringify(userData);                         
                window.sessionStorage.setItem('userObject',userObjectString)
                 },
                 getUserDataFromSession: function() {
                     var userData = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userObject')
                     return JSON.parse(userData);
                 }
                }   

               $("#register-form-header").submit(function(){            

                var uName = $('#userName').val();               
                var upassd=$('#password').val();            

                $.ajax({                                        
                    url:"http://localhost/login/login.php",                     
                    type:"POST",
                    dataType:"json",
                    data:{type:"login",uName:uName,password:upassd},                    

                    ContentType:"application/json",
                    success: function(response){    
                        $.each(response, function(index,value){                           


                        }); 
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(response[0]));

               userData.storeUserDataInSession(response);

                        window.location = 'userProfile.html';   
                        return false;                                   
                    },
                    error: function(err){                           
                        //alert(JSON.stringify(err));
                        alert("fail");
                        window.location.href = 'error.html';
                    }           
                });
                return false; 

        });
        //loadJSON(0);
    });
</script>
```

**javascript in Profile Page**

```
<script>

  $( document ).ready(function() {
       var userData = {
         storeUserDataInSession: function(userData) {
             var userObjectString = JSON.stringify(userData);
             window.sessionStorage.setItem('userObject',userObjectString)
         },
         getUserDataFromSession: function() {
             var userData = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userObject')
             return JSON.parse(userData);
         }
        } 

        var userDataObject=userData.getUserDataFromSession();
        var data=userDataObject[0].userInfo.username;           
        alert(data);            
  }); 
</script>
```

**This profile page success fully able to print HardcodedInfo "Neelabh", I don't know How to send the JSON array of data to other page,** Please check I mentioned **Array of Json Data**,

**PHP code**

```
$result=mysql_query($query);
            $totalRows=mysql_num_rows($result); 
            if($totalRows>0){
                $recipes=array();
                while($recipe=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                    $recipes[]=array('userInfo'=>$recipe);
                }
                echo json_encode($recipes);         
            }
```

**Above code is working code Thanks to  Mateusz Majewski**

Comment: If you want consistency across browsers on mobile devices, you will have to use cookies to pass the data unfortunately. Local/SessionStorage is not supported on Safari's private browsing mode.

Comment: @denisol, could you tell me more about it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var userData = {
 storeUserDataInSession: function(userData) {
     var userObjectString = JSON.stringify(userData);
     window.sessionStorage.setItem('userObject',userObjectString)
 },
 getUserDataFromSession: function() {
     var userData = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userObject')
     return JSON.parse(userData);
 }
}
```

Then in your success() callback you do

```
userData.storeUserDataInSession(response);
```

To retrieve the data you run

```
userData.getUserDataFromSession()
```

Comment: Where I will define this function, var userData = {
 storeUserDataInSession: function(userData) {
     var userObjectString = JSON.stringify(userData);
     window.sessionStorage.setItem('userObject',userObjectString)
 },
 getUserDataFromSession: function() {
     var userData = window.sessionStorage.getItem('userObject')
     return JSON.parse(userData);
 }
}

Comment: @neelabhsingh you can do it in $(document).ready(function() block, but it doesn't matter. It will be accessible from anywhere

Comment: please check We have to use response[0] in userData.storeUserDataInSession(JSON.stringify(response[0]));  I have one more Question How I will get Seperate data, Name, Email, Mobile in userprofile page..

Comment: You can do this: var userDataObject = userData.getUserDataFromSession() . Then you can retrieve the email like this: userDataObject[0].userInfo.Email.

Comment: Thansk for reply, As you suggested me It is not working, var data=userDataObject[0].userInfo.username;

Comment: You need to first run getUserDataFromSession(). so data=userData.getUserDataFromSession()[0].userInfo.username. I just tested it and it works.

Comment: Hi,  I am very sorry your valuable time, I am trying the same but it is not working, I updated code according to you, please have a look,

Comment: Because you passed response[0]. If you do that you don't pass an array to the script that saves the data in sessionStorage. You need to remove [0] or from where you store the data or from where you want to retrieve it so in your case userDataObject.

Comment: Now Its working, Thanks for your time, I accepted your answer and up-vote, If your find my Question is useful then please up-vote